# Установка HTTPS. Centos 7. Apache

Tags: centos, ssl, https, apache2.4

После [установки HTTPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7) на Centos 7 при рестарте Apache командой 
`systemctl restart httpd`
Выдает

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Команда `systemctl status httpd` выдает

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  httpd.service
â— httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           â””â”€nofile.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-05-04 08:17:07 EDT; 51s ago
Docs: man:httpd(8)
man:apachectl(8)
Process: 10999 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 10998 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 10998 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
May 04 08:17:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 04 08:17:07 localhost.localdomain httpd[10998]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost....s message
May 04 08:17:07 localhost.localdomain httpd[10998]: httpd (pid 10680) already running
May 04 08:17:07 localhost.localdomain kill[10999]: kill: cannot find process ""
May 04 08:17:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 04 08:17:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
May 04 08:17:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
May 04 08:17:07 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13980880/4827341